# Repaint JPanel in Swings

Tags: java, swing, action, jpanel, repaint

How to Display the data in Jpanel using Jtabel when i clicked on Checkbox.

when i execute my programme for 1st time jpanel is executing. but second time when  i clicked on checkbox panel which contain jtable does not repaint the jpanel.

please help .

thanks in advance

Comment: basically there are three possibles areas, if you want to reall answer then you have to post your code in http://sscce.org/ form

Answer (score 0):

You need call something like fireTableDataChanged() for refresh JTable. For more details see http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=21114

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method validate() after you added the Jtable to your JPanel.